# Ubuntu One messes up with my thunderbird folders

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have added `.thunderbird` folder to my Ubuntu One's folders to be synced. This is to protect my mails and my thunderbird's settings and plugins.

However, U1 constantly keeps messing up with my folders and a lot of `.u1conflict` files appear in various places in my `.thunderbird` folder. Some of them I see on my thunderbird application when I start it up.

Why is that? Can't I just select my home folders files to be uploaded and *not* synced? 
Or set U1, in case of conflicts, to leave the home folder structure and files as is.

PS: I have subscribed to U1 service and this is important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot simply synchronize everything under your home folder into Ubuntu One. Especially the whole `.thunderbird` or `.mozilla` folders will cause major problems, like the one you are seeing here. They contain many things which are not synchronizable, and which change very often, that will cause many problems similar to this.